# GoogleMaps v3 - some maps don't display in Internet Explorer, do in other browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3

I have a site with three instances of GoogleMaps at

- http://www.meet4rides.com/races-map.php
- http://www.meet4rides.com/submit-a-race.php

and (many pages for this, all off same PHP code):

- http://www.meet4rides.com/races/south-africa/sswc-single-speed-world-championships-2012/cross-country-xc/2012-09-29/61/

The first two links display GoogleMaps correctly on IE, Safari, Chrome and Firefox. The last one does not display the GoogleMap. Not sure what is different or wrong?

As added info - I am only able to test on IE8 - not sure if it works/doesn't work on other versions.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Facebook plugin. That's causing the crash. And in any case, it is outside of the `<head>` section if the document.

```
 ...
</head>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1">
</script>

<body>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware that logging stuff in the browser console might break the launch of GM on IE11 !